# Pareto Chart v.s. machine learning feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, pareto-distribution

A Pareto chart  [could be used to show which factors have the greatest impact and where attention is likely to yield the greatest benefit.](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Pareto-chart-Pareto-distribution-diagram)
Also common machine learning feature selection methods can [simplify model, reduce training times, overfitting etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection)

Both techniques are used to pay attention to some bolded features. I want to what the benefits are to use one policy instead of another one?

Comment: well, I think the chart is visualizing (measured) feature importance while feature selection is measuring feature importance.

Comment: @Frank I think both can be measured and visualized.